# Error when adding a new field to the users table in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I get the following error when adding a new field to the users table.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryExceptionSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'phone' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (mohamed, mm7385845@gmail.com, $2y$10$j746o3piJ0zpz0dwhieK8emio2g38l2rppbkrueJLACDOwVU2uzYC, 2022-02-02 05:50:26, 2022-02-02 05:50:26))

This is the field I want to add:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UmN5.png)

This is my schedule in PHPMyAdmin:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TAcR.png)

**Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    <x-label for="phone" :value="__('Phone')"/>
    <x-input id="phone" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="number" 
             name="phone" :value="old('phone')" required autofocus/>
</div>
```

Comment: Make it nullable, provide a default value or provide a value when creating a user

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I cannot see a phone number in php myadmin. This is a big problem because this is a project and it contains a lot of data.

Comment: That's most likely because it doesn't get inserted/the query fails. You might need to rerun your migrations, you declared `phone` to be a `string` column but your screenshot shows it as `int(11)`

Comment: Sorry I changed it to string and also the same problem it has no value

Comment: Please post the code you use to create/save a user.